# How can I recall the argument of the previous bash command?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command

Is there a way in Bash to recall the argument of the previous command?

I usually do `vi file.c` followed by `gcc file.c`.

Is there a way in Bash to recall the argument of the previous command?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009412/bash-first-argument-of-the-previous-command

Answer (score 730, accepted):

You can use `$_` or `!$` to recall the last argument of the previous command.

Also <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> can be used to recall the last argument of any of the previous commands.

Comment: Also, if you want an arbitrary argument, you can use `!!:1`, `!!:2`, etc. (`!!:0` is the previous command itself.) See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction

Comment: Similar to  `!$`, you use `!^` for the first argument.

Comment: ahh... *nix... you are a thing of beauty... everyday I love you more

Comment: How can we refer to the second to last argument of the previous command? for example, If I gave `echo tiger rabbit`, how can I refer `tiger` at the following command?

Comment: `Alt + .` doesn't work in vi mode. Just FYI, for others who were confused here.

Comment: Note that `!$` print the full command  in the first line when run, while `$_` doesn't.

Comment: This is truly incredible. I love the `M-.` feature. Where is this documented?

Comment: @young_souvlaki see `man bash`, quite literally everything is in that, you just have to actually read it (which is the hard part, but look under 'HISTORY EXPANSION' and 'Commands for Manipulating the History' in particular. For GNU readline related stuff (which is most key binding related stuff outside of bash): https://tiswww.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html#TOCDocumentation

Comment: Is there a way I can make `<alt> + .` work in vi mode? is there a similar workaround for zsh?

Comment: how does it work on mac? I use mac + iterm2, press Alt + . only shows "≥"

Comment: @Chen have to use osx at the moment, have not yet found a shortcut solution

Comment: @Chen Try using `ESC .` See the bash man page, under "Readline Notation": _"[...] Similarly,  meta  keys  are  denoted  by M-key,  so  M-x  means  Meta-X.  (On keyboards without a meta key, M-x means ESC x, i.e., press the Escape key then the x key.  This makes ESC the meta prefix."_

Comment: `$_` in the JavaScript console does a very similar thing!  It returns the last result.  E.g. `2+3` followed by _Enter_ gives `5` and then `$_` followed by _Enter_ also gives `5`.

Answer (score 202):

If the previous command had two arguments, like this

```
ls a.txt b.txt
```

and you wanted the first one, you could type

```
!:1
```

giving

```
a.txt
```

Or if you wanted both, you could type

```
!:1-2
```

giving

```
a.txt b.txt
```

You can extend this to any number of arguments, eg:

```
!:10-12
```

Comment: @RNA, I just tried it again to make sure I didn't include a typo, could you provide a little more detail (eg. ubuntu command line, cygwin for windows? error message? previous line?)

Comment: I am using GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc. The error message is `-bash: :1-2: bad word specifier`

Comment: I get the same thing if there weren't two arguments in the previous line.  Eg. line 1 `ls a.txt` line 2 `ll !:1-2`

Comment: you're right. That is a stupid mistake I made. thanks!

Comment: Also to get all of the arguments, `!:^-$` can be used or of course similar code in combination with numbers.

Comment: [sighs]... what a wonderful way to be distracted at work - just love this

Comment: `!:-3` or `!:3-` works also (for all arguments until/from the 3rd argument)

Answer (score 152):

`!!:n` where `n` is the 0-based position of the argument you want.

For example:

```
echo 'one' 'two'
# "one two"

echo !!:2
# "two"
```

The `!` prefix is used to access previous commands.

Other useful commands:

- `!$` - last argument from previous command
- `!^` - first argument (after the program/built-in/script) from previous command
- `!*` - all arguments from previous command
- `!!` - previous command (often pronounced "bang bang")
- `!n` - command number `n` from `history`
- `!pattern` - most recent command matching `pattern`
- `!!:s/find/replace` - last command, substitute `find` with `replace`

Comment: Instead of `!!:s/find/replace`, you can also `^find^replace`.

Comment: Also: `!*`  - all arguments from the previous command (after the program/built-in/script).
e.g.:

`ls *.tmp *.cache
rm !*`

Comment: Dead links usually earn downvotes, but given the high-quality answer, I will supply a Web Archive link https://web.archive.org/web/20200211203800/https://www.washington.edu/computing/unix/history.html

Answer (score 87):

In the command-line, you can press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>esc</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd>

It cycles through **the last argument** of your previous commands.

Comment: I've always found the `↑` and `↓` keys to work as well.

Comment: @Bucket keys go though previous commands, while the solution provided by Antonio allows to go through previous arguments (last argument of each previous command only)

Answer (score 33):

If you know the number given in the history for a particular command, you can pretty much take any argument in that command using following terms.

Use following to take the second argument from the third command in the history,

`!3:2`

Use following to take the third argument from the fifth last command in the history,

`!-5:3`

Using a minus sign, you ask it to traverse from the last command of the history.

Comment: For some reason, on MacOS 11.6.1 Terminal, 
zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin20.0)
This doesn't work. It looks like zsh ignores the '-' sign - and takes n simply from the start of list. What to do? which 'man' page to consult?

Answer (score 25):

!* runs a new command with all previous arguments.

```
ls /tmp
cd !*
#you are now in /tmp
```

Comment: This didn't work for me on OSX  - had to use `$_` instead.

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, you can use `!$` to recall the last argument of the preceding command.

Comment: Be aware of the key word "last," especially if your command contained multiple arguments.