# How to use arguments from previous command?

Tags: bash, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, input-history

I know that <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> gives you the last argument of the last command.

But I'm interested in first argument of the last command.
Is there a key binding to do so?

On the same lines, is there a generic way of getting the nth argument from the last command?
I know that in a bash script, you can use `$0`, `$1` etc., but these don't work on the commandline.

**Also, what about iterating through the 0th argument of previous commands, like we can do with the last argument by continuously pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>?**

Answer (score 316, accepted):

Just as `M-.` (meta-dot or esc-dot or alt-dot) is the readline function `yank-last-arg`, `M-C-y` (meta-control-y or esc-ctrl-y or ctrl-alt-y) is the readline function `yank-nth-arg`. Without specifying `n`, it yanks the first argument of the previous command.

To specify an argument, press Escape and a number or hold Alt and press a number. You can do <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd>to begin specifying a negative number then release Alt and press the digit (this will count from the end of the list of arguments.

Example:

Enter the following command

```
$ echo a b c d e f g
a b c d e f g
```

Now at the next prompt, type `echo` (with a following space), then

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd> and you'll now see:

```
$ echo a
```

without pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> yet, do the following

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd>  <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>

Now you will see:

```
$ echo ace
```

By the way, you could have put the `echo` on the line by selecting argument 0:

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>

**Edit:**

To answer the question you added to your original:

You can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd> then repeatedly press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> to step through the previous commands (arg 0). Similarly <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd> then repeating <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> would allow you to step through the previous next-to-last arguments.

If there is no appropriate argument on a particular line in history, the bell will be rung.

If there is a particular combination you use frequently, you can define a macro so one keystroke will perform it. This example will recall the second argument from previous commands by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd>. You could choose any available keystroke you prefer instead of this one. You can press it repeatedly to step through previous ones.

To try it out, enter the macro at a Bash prompt:

```
bind '"\eY": "\e2\e."'
```

To make it persistent, add this line to your `~/.inputrc` file:

```
"\eY": "\e2\e."
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work for arg 0 or negative argument numbers.

Comment: When looking for keyboard shortcuts for bash/readline, I like running ```bind -lp``` and looking at the current bindings.

Comment: @ChadSkeeters: And `-s` (new in Bash 4) lists macros created using `-x`.

Comment: Note that you can use the digit argument with `M-.` as well: `Alt-3` `Alt-Ctrl-y` for example equals holding `Alt` and typing `3.`. If you type `3.` that multiple times without releasing `Alt` you go through the third arguments of your previous command lines.

Comment: @dessert: I say as much in my second paragraph and then show an example.

Comment: @ChadSkeeters, thanks for the warning that there would be *hundreds* of entries!  Lol.

Comment: `Alt-3` `Alt-.` (, `Alt-.`, ...) (cycling through 3rd argument) is what I have been looking for for years

Answer (score 411):

`!$` gets the last element of the previous command line argument.

Comment: `!:3` gets you the third one

Comment: !* gets you all of em

Comment: `!!` gets you the entire last command. Useful if you forgot to use `sudo`.

Comment: `!:1-2` gets you all but the last of 3 arguments

Comment: `Alt + .` also gets the last element of the previous command line argument (in bash)

Comment: Just a word of warning - if you use combined arguments like `echo foo{,bar} baz`, the command is recorded as printed and expands afterwards. With the above, using `echo !:1` after resolves to `echo foo{,bar}` and then expands to `echo foo foobar`

Comment: Additionally, combining commands like `echo a b c && echo !:2` still count as one command for your history, so  `echo foo && echo !:2bar` won't output `foo` + `foobar`, but rather `foo` and `(previous command's second argument)bar`

Comment: For more information, the reference for the above excellent comments is here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Event-Designators.html#Event-Designators

Comment: While true, that is not a keybinding, which is what the question asked for.

Answer (score 288):

To use the first argument, you can use `!^` or `!:1`

Example:

```
$ echo a b c d e 
a b c d e
$ echo !^
echo a
a

$ echo a b c d e 
a b c d e
$ echo !:1
echo a
a
```

Since your question is about using any other arguments, here are some useful ones:

```
!^      first argument
!$      last argument
!*      all arguments
!:2     second argument

!:2-3   second to third arguments
!:2-$   second to last arguments
!:2*    second to last arguments
!:2-    second to next to last arguments

!:0     the command
!!      repeat the previous line
```

The first four forms are more often used.  The form `!:2-` is somewhat counter-intuitive, as it doesn't include the last argument.

Comment: Is there a way to get the second-last item? i.e. get `file3` from `mv file1 file2 file3 target/`?

Comment: I liked this answer a lot and just for the completeness sake, I suggest to also add a line telling about '!-2' syntax that allows you to access previous to previous command.

Comment: @bbv Also for even more completeness the command '!2' which allows you to access the second entry in the history (if it's still available depending on your history settings). Useful if you display the history number in each prompt.

Comment: There's also `!:-2` which gives you everything up until the 2nd argument. In this case `echo a b`.

Answer (score 69):

I liked @larsmans answer so much I had to learn more.   Adding this
answer to help others find the man page section and know what to
google for:

```
$ man  -P 'less -p ^HISTORY\ EXPANSION' bash
<...>
Word Designators

Word designators are used to select desired words from the event.
A : separates the event specification from the word designator.
It may be omitted if the word designator begins with a ^, $, *, -,
or %.  Words are numbered from the beginning of the line, with the
first word being denoted by 0 (zero).  Words are inserted into the
current line separated by single spaces.

   0 (zero)
          The zeroth word.  For the shell, this is the command word.
   n      The nth word.
   ^      The first argument.  That is, word 1.
   $      The last argument.
   %      The word matched by the most recent ‘?string?’ search.
   x-y    A range of words; ‘-y’ abbreviates ‘0-y’.
   *      All of the words but the zeroth.
          This is a synonym for ‘1-$’.  
          It is not an error to use * if there is just one word in
          the event; the empty string is returned in that case.
   x*     Abbreviates x-$.
   x-     Abbreviates x-$ like x*, but omits the last word.

   If a word designator is supplied without an event
   specification, the previous command is used as the event.
```

Answer (score 25):

## Tested on Ubuntu 18.04

---

### To insert previous arguments:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>: insert last argument from last command.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>: insert #nth last argument from last command.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> , <kbd>#</kbd> , <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, **zsh:** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>: insert #nth first argument from last command.

*In Linux you can repeat commands to go back in history*

### Example:

Last command is:

```
mv foo bar
```

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>: insert first argument of last command = `mv`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>: insert last 2nd argument of last command = `foo`
- <kbd>up</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>: last command without the last word = `mv foo`

### General shortcuts

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>: removes last word from cursor
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>: removes next word from cursor
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>: cuts everything after cursor
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, **zsh:** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>: cuts everything before cursor
- **zsh:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>: cuts the entire command *(In bash you can combine <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>)*
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>: paste characters previously cut with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd>: undo last edit *(very useful when exceeding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>)*
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd>: move to last word
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>: move to next word
- <kbd>home</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>: move to start of line
- <kbd>end</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>: move to end of line

### To iterate through the arguments in a previous command

#### only works in zsh

run or add this to your `~/.zshrc`

```
autoload -Uz copy-earlier-word
zle -N copy-earlier-word
bindkey "^[:" copy-earlier-word
```

Now use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to go as back as you want, then use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd> to iterate through the arguments

Assuming last command is

```
echo 1 2 3 4 5
```

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>: `5`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>: `4`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>: `3`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>: `2`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>: `1`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>: `echo`

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34861762/3163120

### To see all shortcuts available

- **bash:** `bind -lp`
- **zsh:** `bindkey -L`

---

I'm keeping this up-to-date here: https://github.com/madacol/knowledge/blob/master/bash-zsh_TerminalShorcuts.md

Comment: `Alt .` on Zsh on Mac is typing `≥` 

Comment: Esc . works, even though it only works for the last one. You can't keep typing to go back in time. Maybe it would be worth updating the answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: You could run `bindkey -L` in **zsh** to see all shortcuts binded, maybe it it will help pinpoint the issue, or even find other useful commands.
In my case for example: the binding `Alt .` is defined as `bindkey "^[." insert-last-word`. 
`Ctrl L` (to clear screen) -> `bindkey "^L" clear-screen`. 
`Alt+Ctrl h` -> `bindkey "^[^H" backward-kill-word` (same as `Ctrl w` to remove last word)

Comment: @Madacol I can also see on bind keys the mentioned copy-earlier-word as  `bindkey "^[^_" copy-prev-word`

Comment: Some of these shortcuts depend on terminal used. E.g. in xfce4-terminal Alt-2 switches to the second tab.

Answer (score 19):

!^   may be the command for the first argument. i'm not sure if there is a way to get the nth.

Comment: it is !:n as suggested above

Comment: Is there a way to get the n-th last item, so like `!:n`, but counting from the end rather than the start?

Answer (score 16):

You can also get arguments from any command in your history!

```
$ echo a b c d e f g
a b c d e f g
$ echo build/libs/jenkins-utils-all-0.1.jar
build/libs/jenkins-utils-all-0.1.jar
$ history | tail -5
  601  echo build/libs/jenkins-utils-all-0.1.jar
  602  history | tail -10
  603  echo a b c d e f g
  604  echo build/libs/jenkins-utils-all-0.1.jar
  605  history | tail -5
$ echo !-3:4
echo d
d
$ echo !604:1
echo build/libs/jenkins-utils-all-0.1.jar
build/libs/jenkins-utils-all-0.1.jar
```

Answer (score 13):

!^ will get you the first param, !$ will get you the last param, !:*n* will get you the nth element.

Answer (score 4):

Basically it has a use in yanking **previous** (command's) **arguments**.

For instance, if the following command is issued:

```
echo Hello, world how are you today?
```

then, `Hello,` will be the first argument, and `today?` the **sixth**, that is the last one; meaning it can be referenced by typing:

<kbd>Alt+6</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-6</kbd>

---

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is traditionally denoted as a hat character `^` prepended to keys names, and <kbd>Alt</kbd> as `M-` that is ***M***eta prefix.

So the above shortcut can be redefined as `^My` to yank.

---

Also, there is *hats* substitution shortcut in the command line:

```
echo Hello, world!

^Hello^Bye

Bye, world!
```

to substitute the previous command's **first matched string**, meaning:

```
Hello, world! Hello, people!

^Hello^Bye
```

would result in:

```
Bye, world! Hello, people!
```

leaving the second match (`hello`) unchanged.

> Note: Do not leave **space between hats**, or the operation won't work.

---

The above is just a shortcut for:

```
!:s/Hello/Bye
```

event-level(*) substitution for the first found (matched) string in the previous command, while prefixing the first part with the `g` switch will apply to **the whole line** ***g***lobally:

```
echo Hello, world! Hello, people!

!:gs/Hello/Bye

Bye, world! Bye, people!
```

as usually being done in other related commands such as `sed`, `vi`, and in `regex` (regular expression) - a standart way to search (*match string*).

> No, you can't do `!:sg/Hello/Bye` or `!:s/Hello/Bye/g` here, that's the **syntax**!

---

- ! is for events; event might be understood as command output or operation done in the commands history.

---

That's what I understood by using it myself and trying things on my own from what I read from various sources including manual pages, blogs, and forums.

Hope it will shed some light into mysterious ways of `bash`, the Bourne-Again shell (a play on `sh` shell, which itself is called Bourne shell after its inventor's last name), what is default shell in many distributions including servers (*server OS's*).

Answer (score 1):

The method described at the end of the accepted answer also works with the zeroth argument for me. I have these lines in my `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\en": "\e0\e."
"\em": "\e1\e."
"\e,": "\e2\e."
```

`\e2\e.` has the advantage over `\e2\e\C-y` that it cycles through previous commands if it is pressed repeatedly instead of inserting the second argument of the previous command multiple times.

To insert the whole previous command, you can type `!!\e^`. `\e^` is [`shell-expand-line`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Commands.html#index-shell_002dexpand_002dline-_0028M_002dC_002de_0029).

Answer (score 1):

For pasting 1th argument, press and hold down Alt key, and while it is down, hit the '1' key followed by the '.' key.

For pasting n-th argument, replace the '1' key above with the corresponding number key.

If this does not work, your terminal emulator may be catching the Alt key before it gets to shell. Some terminals (xfce4-terminal) allow turning off  the "Alt-" shortcuts in the configuration file.

Credit to Jonas Eberle, I've fished this out from his comment to another answer here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a mac you will tend to get extended characters with ctrl+letter. I have my right-of-space-bar-option key defined as meta in my terminal (iTerm2) set up. This means I use the key to navigate by word and pull parameters from previous commands.