# How to rename file with bash by adding first symbol - dot?

Tags: bash, file-rename

I would like to rename my file from `myscript.js` to `.myscript.js`. How can I do it with bash? I've tried different options like `mv myscript.js \.*`, but it doesn't work. I've tried to experiment by adding non-dot symbol like - `mv myscript.js m*`, but now I don't even know where my file is (of course, I have a copy ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying too hard.

`mv myscript.js .myscript.js`

Answer (score 3):

Brace expansion

```
mv {,.}myscript.js
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rename` utility to rename all `*.js` file by placing a dot before them:

```
rename 's/(.+\.js)/.$1/' *.js
```

Or in pure BASH use this for loop:

```
for i in *.js; do mv "$i" ".$i"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use patterns as the target of `mv` (or `cp` for that matter). The command won't do what you want or expect, most of the time: Bash will expand the pattern at the moment when you run the command, using the file names as they were *before* your command was executed. So `.*` matches nothing (since the file doesn't exist, yet) and `m*` will match any file or folder which starts with `m`. Since you didn't get an error, chances are that the last match was a folder.

There is no way to access the previous parameter of the current command. If you want to avoid typing too much, then use <kbd>Tab</kbd> for both file names (so you end up with `mv myscript.js myscript.js`) and then use <kbd>Ctrl+Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Right</kbd> to move quickly to the start of the second argument to insert the missing `.`.

You can access the [parameters of the previous command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009412/bash-how-to-use-arguments-from-previous-command), though. But that's not a feature of BASH - it's a feature of readline.