# Alt+number+dot and Alt+comma in Zsh and Bash

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, zsh, oh-my-zsh

In Bash, we can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to select the n*th* argument of previous commands, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to select the previous commands. They cycles through the history.

For example:

```
$ ls 1 2
$ echo 10 20
```

Now press and hold Alt, and press 0 then dot, it will show "echo". Without releasing <kbd>Alt</kbd>, press <kbd>.</kbd> again, it will show "ls". Use 1 in the same operation will show 10 and 1, etc. Pressing Alt and comma shows the whole command line in the history. Also <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>.</kbd> show the last argument of the commands in history.

Note that all of these operations just insert the argument (or whole command line) to the current cursor. They don't change what's already there in the current command line.

I am using Zsh and the latest Oh-My-Zsh package but it seems the behavior is different:

- Zsh has the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to show the last argument of commands.
- The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> is the same as Bash (shows the comman), but
  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> shows the last n*th* argument, i.e., <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> in above
  case shows 20 and 2.
- The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> doesn't display the whole commands in history.

How to do the same thing in Zsh? Thanks.

Comment: Alt-comma isn't bound to anything by default that I'm aware of. The default binding for "last command from history" is ctrl-p (and ctrl-n is next command in history for if you go too far back, etc.). (See [Commands for History](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Commands-For-History) in the bash manual for example.) What does `bind -q previous-history` output for you? (I get `previous-history can be invoked via "\C-p", "\eOA", "\e[A".`)

Comment: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html. Learn `zle` and `bindkey`. ZLE is far more powerful and customizable than bash/readline, that's the only thing I'll say.

Comment: Ctrl-p and Ctrl-n work the same as Bash. They just replace the current command line with last/next command from history. I guess I have to learn zle and bindkey. Just was surprised there were not these useful shortcuts.

Answer (score 12):

Looking for this feature I came across [this blogpost](http://chneukirchen.org/blog/archive/2013/03/10-fresh-zsh-tricks-you-may-not-know.html) by Christian Neukirchen:

> 1. You probably know M-. to insert the last argument of the previous line. Sometimes, you want to insert a different argument. There are a few options: Use history expansion, e.g. !:-2 for the third word on the line before (use TAB to expand it if you are not sure), or use M-. with a prefix argument: M-2 M-.
>
> Much nicer however is:
>
> ```
> autoload -Uz copy-earlier-word
> zle -N copy-earlier-word
> bindkey "^[m" copy-earlier-word
> ```
>
> Then, M-m will copy the last word of the current line, then the second last word, etc. But with M-. you can go back in lines too! Thus:
>
> ```
> % echo a b c
> % echo 1 2 3
> % echo <M-.><M-.><M-m>
> % echo b
> ```
>
> Man, I wish I knew that earlier!

In this text, `M` is referring to the `Meta` key, aka `Alt`. So in theory this should work out of the box, as Christian says. So I went to try this and yes, it *did* work out of the box.

The zle widgets in charge of this behavior are `insert-last-word` ─which is `ALT`+`.`─ and `digit-argument` ─which is `ALT`+`Number`.

Here's the relevant `bindkey` output:

```
$ bindkey -L | grep '\^\[[.0-9]'
bindkey "^[." insert-last-word
bindkey "^[0" digit-argument
bindkey "^[1" digit-argument
bindkey "^[2" digit-argument
bindkey "^[3" digit-argument
bindkey "^[4" digit-argument
bindkey "^[5" digit-argument
bindkey "^[6" digit-argument
bindkey "^[7" digit-argument
bindkey "^[8" digit-argument
bindkey "^[9" digit-argument
```

so check that those appear and try again. You can update your original question with the output of the shown `bindkey` command to help narrow down the issue, or open one directly in [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues) with the details.