# Insert first word of previous command in ZSH command line

Tags: zsh

In zsh (and bash), I can do <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to insert the last argument of the previous command into the command line.

Is there something similar for the first word?

Example: After running `/bin/ls -l /tmp`, I want it to insert `/bin/ls`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found this in a .zshrc

```
insert-first-word () { zle insert-last-word -- -1 1 }
zle -N insert-first-word
bindkey '^[_' insert-first-word
```

then <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>_</kbd>

Comment: This can be found in my .zshrc now, too ;) I only changed the shortcut to Alt+, as comma is left to the dot key, which made a bit more sense to me. I choose this as the accepted answer as it is more convenient than the [built-in solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48230185/3449673) I found... and it encouraged me to learn some [ZLE](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide04.html). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found [Alt+number+dot and Alt+comma in Zsh and Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571398/altnumberdot-and-altcomma-in-zsh-and-bash) which basically answers my question:

In zsh, you can do <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

It is a bit unwieldy to press three buttons for this, but it is built-in and works.