# Open blank new file with the same name as existing file in one step, in VIM?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, vim, vi

Say I have stuff.txt, filled with stuff, in the current directory. And I want to get rid of it, and make a new stuff.txt in vim. Obviously I could do

```
rm stuff.txt
vi stuff.txt
```

But that's two steps, the horror! Is there a way to consolidate this into one vim/vi call without invoking rm? Perphaps some -option on vim that I somehow missed when looking in the manual?

Obvious workaround is to create something like this, in a file called, for example, new.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm $1
vim $1
```

and then do from the command line, ./new.sh stuff.txt, but that seems a bit un-eleagant. I'm on ubuntu using the standard bash.

Comment: `> stuff.txt` and `vim !$`?

Comment: Would 2 commands but shortcuts work? You can leverage bash and get the last argument either via `!$` (e.g. `vim !$`) or use `M-.` See post: [How to use arguments from previous command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4009412/438329)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can start `vim` like this:

```
vim -c '%d' stuff.txt
```

Here `-c` option is:

> `-c <command>`      Execute `<command>` after loading the first file

`%d` will delete all lines from file after opening the file.

Comment: Or `vim -c '%d' -c 'w' stuff.txt`, and after `:q!` or `:e!` you won't get stuff back. When you also want something against `u` (undo), try `vim -c '%d' -c 'w' -c 'e' stuff.txt`.

Comment: Being able to use undo is probably the best option, not to mention with persistent history it becomes even more useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
rmed () {
    local EDITOR=${EDITOR:-vi}
    [ -f "$1" ] && rm "$1"
    command $EDITOR "$1"
}
```

This is a shell function that will remove the given file, then open `$EDITOR` (or `vi` if `$EDITOR` is not set) with a file of the same name.

```
$ rmed somefile
```

Answer (score 0):

You write a function/alias/script to do what you want.
I have a script called `vix`, that will start writing a shell script (shebang line and chmod +x) when the argument is not existing or only chmod and edit it when it exists.
Perhaps you should use `virm` because I do not like the sound of `rmvi`.