# Fish shell: variable with last argument

Tags: fish

What is a fish shell equivalent of `mkdir -p foo/bar/baz/quux && cd $_`?

I know about `$history[1]`, but here I need only last argument of the previous command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

fish doesn't support a last argument variable unfortunately.

An efficient interactive way to do this is to make the directory:

```
> mkdir -p foo/bar/baz/quux
```

Then type cd and the first character of the path.

```
> cd f
```

At this point fish will probably autosuggest the whole path. If not you can press alt-up to do a history token search and it will certainly find it.

A scripting way to do it would be:

```
set path foo/bar/baz/quux && mkdir -p $path && cd $path
```

Answer (score 9):

As [suggested in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4010170/6656775)
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> cycles arguments from previous commands at cursor input:

```sh
mkdir -p ~/fish/previous/arg/demo
cd 
#  ^ hit Alt + .
cd ~/fish/previous/arg/demo
```

Answer (score 5):

Fish has no shortcut for this, you'll have to repeat that argument.

Or if it's for interactive use, press alt-up to cycle through older arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I also found the lack of `$_` annoying. A (somewhat hacky) solution is to create a function like this:

```
function cdl
    echo "$history[1]" | read --array --tokenize result
    cd "$result[-1]"
end
```

So now you can type `cdl` instead of `cd $_` to change to the directory you just created.

EDIT: Added correct quoting and `--tokenize` which was added in this [PR](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/3823) in version 3.1. Now it works correctly with directory names that contain spaces.