# Is there a way to use repeated parts of command line just once?

Tags: linux, shell

I need to use plural commands sequence frequently, like:

```
xelatex a-tex-file.tex && xelatex a-tex-file.tex
```

to create a latex catalog. Or:

```
dot -Tpdf -o a-dot-file{.pdf,.dot} && evince a-dot-file.pdf
```

to view a pdf file after being compiled immediately to check if I correctly modify the graph file described by dot language.
And so on.

To prevent clerical error I want to use repeated command line parts(such as filename) by any possible ways, a bit like:

```
xelatex a-tex-file.tex && xelatex $2
```

and maybe

```
dot -Tpdf -o a-dot-file.pdf ${3%.*}.dot && evince $3
```

Maybe set (positional) variables or make a script can get it but I hope it can change the environment as less as possible, and I don't think it is sensible to make scripts for every command permutation, or set/unset variable on every time.

So is there any way to use repeated command line parts in just current command line more "temporarily" in various shells?

Comment: Define functions to do what you want and use positional parameters in them?

Comment: You can use `!:3` for the 3rd parameter of last command for example. Try running `help bind` and `bind -pl` as well.

Comment: Actually, there's already a question with a good answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32332694/2836621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bash, `!#` is the history expansion for the current command line that you've typed so far.

```sh
$ echo foobar && !#:0 !#:1
echo foobar && echo foobar
foobar
foobar
```

The second one (with the brace expansion) will be tricky because the history expansion happens *before* the brace expansion, so you'd have to do something goofy like

```sh
$ dot -Tpdf a-dot-file{.dot,.pdf} && evince !#:2:s/{.dot,.pdf}/.pdf/
```

and it's absolutely not worth bothering. You'd use a function for that:

```sh
dot-evince() {
    local pdf=${1/%.dot/.pdf}
    dot -Tpdf "$1" "$pdf" && evince "$pdf"
}

dot-evince a-dot-file.dot
```