# What is the fastest way to get the previous command in shell?

Tags: linux

I am in UNIX, and what is the fastest way to get the previous command in shell? Right now I am using `!:0` to get the previous command, but I am not sure if there is a better alternative. Let say I have this:

```
git add .
!:0 commit -m "Inital" //!:0 will be git
```

Is there an even faster way? `!:0` is not easy to type.

Comment: What about `Alt-0` `Alt-.`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use arguments from previous command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009412/how-to-use-arguments-from-previous-command)

Answer (score 0):

I use up arrow on my termianl to get the latest commands i ran, you may also use history, and to run any command from history use !.