# Recall all arguments from a previously executed command in bash shell

Tags: bash

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371294/how-can-i-recall-the-argument-of-the-previous-bash-command) gives the pointer on how to recall the arguments of the last successfully executed command in the command line.

I wanted to access all the arguments of a particular command from the shell history.

To me only this syntax works

```
ls f1 f2 f3
file !ls:1-3 --> file f1 f2 f3
```

And, if I use **!*** which should give all the arguments of previous command throws error

```
file !ls:!*
-bash: !: unrecognized history modifier
```

I can only use this syntax (i.e) all arguments of last executed command.

```
file !*
```

Problem with the above methods are if I had executed **ls** with some option, for eg: **ls -l**, then the **file** command would have thrown a different output as the option of **ls** would be considered as first argument in this case.

Comment: `all the arguments (part of argument list)` - that's not clear to. Do you want all arguments or part of argument list? In `ls -l file` command `-l file` are the arguments in `Bash` understanding.

Comment: Ah, edited and removed that portion "(part of argument list)". Sorry for the confusion. It is all the arguments only

Comment: *all the arguments* but if you ran `ls -l f1 f2 f3` you want to get just `f1 f2 f3` and not `-l f1 f2 f3` right?

Comment: `-l` *is* an argument. The shell doesn't know to treat it differently than any other argument, and `ls` only treats it differently because of the leading `-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try leaving out the second `!`:

```
$ ls foo bar baz
foo bar baz
$ echo !ls:*
echo foo bar baz
foo bar baz
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers OP's question. If you used `ls -l` as OP did you would get `-l` in the output and OP doesn't want that.

Answer (score 1):

`!ls` returns the last `ls` command. If you want the second to last or even an older `ls` execution you can use `history` to retrieve the command you want

```
history | grep ls

355  ls foo bar baz
446  ls -a
447  ls -ah
```

And then use @Jon solution or yours to get the arguemnts

```
echo !355:*
```