# Bash - How to string replace part of the last argument of the last command when using '>' to redirect the output stream

Tags: bash, replace, terminal, one-liner

in bash I have got something like this:

- `$ <cmd> <arg1> input_file_123.txt > ouput_file_123.txt`

I want to reuse `input_file_123.txt` to name the output file but replace let's say "input" with "output".

I found this: [How can I recall the argument of the previous bash command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371294/how-can-i-recall-the-argument-of-the-previous-bash-command),

tried this:

- `$ <cmd> <arg1> input_file_123.txt > !$:s/input/output`

but it says "substitution failed".

I would need it to be a one-liner I can use within a jupyter notebook.

Thx for your help!

Comment: do you also want/need to strip the `.txt` from the input file name? or should the output filename also have a `.txt` extension?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. I corrected it in the post. The output should be `output_file_123.txt`

Comment: And I'm a little said about the -1 because I actually DID put research effort into my question

Comment: you should read up about bash programming. to be writing programs like that and not just a single command. then things like this become obvious.

Comment: @john-jones: So what is the obvious answer then? Or what would I specifically need to search for regarding bash programming? Bash programming is a brought topic, isn't it? I honestly tried to figure it out for a good amount of time. I also got O'Reillys "Linux in a nut shell" or whatever the english title is and know some stuff. But what I want to do seems to advanced (for me) and too specific to stumble across in a "bash programming beginners how-to".

Comment: I think it would be clever for you to read and glossarise, something like this https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0596005954?ref_=as_li_ss_tl&language=en_US&ie=UTF8&linkCode=gs2&linkId=84b27c07d94d865bbfb7f412f4c60461&tag=365blottochal-21. and then get used to write an entire script, in which you are running commands like the one you are running. then you could easily use variables instead of strings. And once you are using variables, concatenating them in miscellaneous ways becomes the norm. And you would then have the base string, and concatenate infront of them 'input' and 'output'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option:

```
# store the input file in a variable

$ infile='input_file_123.txt'

# use parameter substitution to change 'input' to 'output'

$ <cmd> <arg1> "${infile}" > "${infile//input/output}"
```

Not sure I understand the `'one-liner'` requirement but fwiw:

```
$ infile='input_file_123.txt'; <cmd> <arg1> "${infile}" > "${infile//input/output}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save `_file_123.txt` as a variable: `var="_file_123.txt"`.
After that you can call the name by using: `input${var}` and `output${var}`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This I knew, but it is supposed to be a one liner I want to fire off from a jupyter notebook using "!".